# How do I search for businesses in a specific area on Google and sort by rating?

Tags: google-search, google-maps

I'm having a heck of a time figuring out which of Google's properties will allow me to do this seemingly simple search:

I want a list of businesses in a specific area, sorted by customer rating.

For instance, I might search for:

- Indian Food in San Francisco
- Dry Cleaning in Los Angeles
- Locksmith in New York

How do I get a list of results sorted by review score?

I've tried using Google Maps, which has the ratings, but doesn't seem to let me sort by rating.

I thought Google Places would be the tool I'm looking for, but when I go there, it just asks if I want to rate or add my own business.  It's not clear how I just search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short answer

At this time, it's not possible to sort Google Search / Maps results of local business by rating.

## Explanation

By design, Google serve results sorted by relevance. They offer filters but not sorting settings.

## References

- [How to search on Google - Google Search Help](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/134479?hl=en)
- [How Google Search Works - Google Search Console Help](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/70897?hl=en)
- [Improve your local ranking on Google - Google My Business Help](https://support.google.com/business/answer/7091?hl=en)